# Can't make this if statememt work

Tags: php, while-loop

```
while ( $org = $orgid->fetch_array()) {
    $getorg = "SELECT Name FROM organisations WHERE ID='" . $org['orgid'] . "'";
    $orgname = $db->query($getorg) or die ($db->error());
    if ( $org['orgid'] !== false ) {
            echo("<td>" . $orgname->fetch_object()->Name . "</td>" );
        $hasOrg = true;
    }
    else {
        echo("<td>Player not in an org.</td>");
    }
}
```

[Link To Image](http://puu.sh/8fk07.png)

Here is my code, and above is the result (the link).

CG Staff is the organization, for players with it.

The query only has two results, so that is why it is returning true all the time. How, though, can I make it say something in the  for rows in the table that don't have a result?

Comment: From your code I can tell that `$org['orgid']` will always be `true`.

Comment: is there any chance the column value to be `false` ?

Comment: no, since is not a boolean type, but you can check if it is empty or if the id,(i guess int type) is not x number

Comment: Ah, you are right. That is because there are only two entries in the table, because the other results are coming from a different table. How do I make it show "Player does not have an org." in all the other slots, even though there are only two entries in the database?

Comment: I didn't mean because you have two results you will always get `true`. But as long as you have results from your first query, the `$org['orgid']` will always be true. Please show the first query too, because it is related.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement

```
if ( $org['orgid'] !== false )
```

$org['orgid'] has to be identical to FALSE. A zero(0) or NULL will evaluate as true, make sure that column contains a FALSE.

You could re-write this like this to evaluate the contents of $org['orgid']

```
if ( $org['orgid'] ) {
        echo("<td>" . $orgname->fetch_object()->Name . "</td>" );
        $hasOrg = true;
} else {
    echo("<td>Player not in an org.</td>");
}
```